Получение access_token без привязки к ip address в VK api
Есть скрипт который пересылает сообщения из моего профиля в vk в бот в телеграмме, все работает ровно до того момента пока я не начинаю запускать скрипт не с локальной тачки а с сервера.
Ошибка следующая:
User authorization failed: access_token was given to another ip address. request_params = {'method': 'messages.getConversations', 'oauth': '1', 'v': '5.131'}
Токен получаю через https://vkhost.github.io
Настройки следующие, id приложения указан vk.com

судя по той информации что нашел если указывать - Доступ в любое время то токен можно использовать с любого устройства. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и что я делаю не так
